# How to get user object based on username and not the (id, pk) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am having struggles viewing other profiles with the users username in the URL, I am able to see there pages with the users ID, but not with there usernames, this is the url now http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/30/, but I want to have this http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/reedlyons/. I know I could do it with the get_object_or_404, but I was wondering if there is another way around that.

Here is my views.py

```
def profile_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.")
    if profile:
        context['id'] = profile.id
        context['user'] = profile.user
        context['email'] = profile.email
        context['profile_picture'] = profile.profile_picture.url

        return render(request, "main/profile_visit.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("user/<user_id>/", views.profile_view, name = "get_profile"),
...
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = False, blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default.png', upload_to = "img/%y", null = True, blank = True)
    banner_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'bg_image.png', upload_to = "img/%y", null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: If I understand the question, you need to fetch the user based on `username`, not `user_id`, right?

Comment: Correct, I did try and put username instead of user_id, but it still returns the user_id.

Comment: Add ur `Profile` model to the question, please!

Comment: Got it, just add it @MohamedHamza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def profile_view(request, username):
    context = {}
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        profile = user.profile

        context['username'] = user.username
        context['email'] = profile.email
        context['bio'] = profile.bio
        context['profile_picture'] = profile.profile_picture.url

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.")        

    return render(request, "main/profile_visit.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("user/<str:username>/", views.profile_view, name = "get_profile"),
]
```

make sure every `user` instance attached with `profile`

Comment: Right now, it's taking me to the main/profile_visit.html, but it's showing me my own page basically

Comment: Should I put anything in front of my tags? Like <p class="name">{{user}}</p>

Comment: I'm not familiar with the front-end staff but try that: `<p class="username">{{username}}</p> ` , `<p class="email">{{email}}</p> ` and so on so forth.